# Better way to fire off my Ajax Function for a like button?

Tags: javascript, ajax

i am developing a web site. there i add a facility that can users to put likes for comments.
i am going to use ajax to pass the deatiles about liking.
so i wrote function `AjaxReq(cid);` for ajax. and for like button i set to fire off that function by `onClick="AjaxReq('14')"`. in this way i have to do this for all buttons.

so..i want to know are there any way to do this without using methode like this.`onClick="AjaxReq('14')"`

i have seen on some web apps, that they don not use methodes like `onClick` to fire off there functions.  please give me some hints to do my like buttons.

**Note:** i am not using jquery

Comment: are you using any sort of library?  or is this all raw javascript?

Comment: Are you certain that they're not using the onclick event? While there may not be a handler defined in the HTML, you could easily attach one using javascript. To check for such an attached handler, consider the "Questions" button at the top of this page. Its markup is `<a id="nav-questions" href="/questions">Questions</a>`. Yet if you right-click it (in Chrome) and select inspect element, you'll be taken to its tag in the html. If you then click the 'Event Listeners' tab in the pane on the right, you'll see that it has handlers for `blur,click,closePopups,keydown,mousedown,mouseout,mouseover`.

Comment: @hellatan no, im not using library. i coded everyting.

Comment: are you opposed to using any sort of library?  It might sound great to code things 100% yourself, but sometimes you need to know when it's ok to use a library.  If this is something that needs to be ported around to different sites as widget, I totally get why you would need to develop up with just pure JS.  However, if this is a site you are creating, I think throwing a library in there will really help with a lot of things, especially cross-browser ajax issues and event handlers.